# What is the maximum number of AVP points you can get?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

I started the game a while back, played for 60h or so then took a break (to finish other games :) ).

Anyway... at launch there were a ton of posts saying AVP is limited to 20. After I started again (last week, so there were a few patches) I hit 20... then 21... then 22. And it all worked well. So I just guessed they raised the cap.

Now I did the Meridian mission and got 2 more levels (24). But... immediately after I checked screen they went back to 22 (press esc, see 24, then press esc see 22 again). So... I did what any other normal person would do and loaded back the game, ran to AVP console and allocated all pods. Then pressed esc and seen 22 points again, but the pods were already allocated (and they remained like that). This is obviously a bug.

My question is... did they raise the cap (and the bug is that the points disappeared), or they didn't raise the cap and the bug is that I got those points in the first place?

All threads I find saying the cap is 20 are old. Does anyone know any new post regarding that? Or any change log?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They raised the cap to 29 in a patch a few weeks ago. [Patch notes](http://blog.bioware.com/2017/05/09/mass-effect-andromeda-patch-1-06-notes/)

Personally (though I'm not quite sure, I finished the game a month ago), I reached Level 25 (in theory, it was still capped at 20 back then, but judged by the amount of extra AVP I had back then) with 98% game completion